# Inserting Post Method with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I'm learning Kotlin, part of my project is to integrate JSON as an object and use the POST method to change or add information.
I'm not able to do this, I need help.

```
package com.example.blog

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*


data class Relatorio(
        val titulo: String,
        val autor: String,
        val serie: String
)


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Bradesco")
class BradescoController {


    @GetMapping()
    public fun relatorio(): Relatorio {
        val result = Relatorio(
                "Investimentos",
                "Luis Felipe",
                "Bradesco Analises"
        )
                return result
}
    @PostMapping
    @RequestMapping( @RequestBody "/empiricus")
    public fun relatorio2() {
        "titulo" = "Contra as altas taxas"
        return "Atualizado";


    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some annotations are out of place in your `relatorio2` method. You want to register a REST-endpoint for the POST-method and the path `/empiricus`.
This can happen one of two ways:

1. Annotate the method with `@RequestMapping(value = "/empiricus", method = RequestMethod.POST)`
2. Annotate the method with `@PostMapping("/empiricus") (you can omit the method-parameter from the example above, since this a shortcut for exactly that.

The `@RequestBody` annotation needs to be placed in the parameter of the `relatorio2` method since it tells Spring to map the POST request-body to an object.
Therefore the method should look something like this:

```
@PostMapping("/empiricus")
public fun relatorio2(@RequestBody relatorio: Relatorio) {
    "titulo" = "Contra as altas taxas"
    return "Atualizado";
}
```

Since you added a path on class level, the complete path to call the method is `/Bradesco/empiricus`. When the object is available in the `relatorio2` method, you can use it in your business logic.